# accept and canDrop (useDrop properties) not working properly to prevent taking duplicate item types

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm trying to create a react component that lets the user drag randomly generated words of a handful of categories to build a short phrase. The draggable word elements each have one of these categories as their type. I want the drop target that they're being dragged to only accept one of each word category, and I've run into really strange behavior from the library for this seemingly simple operation.

I initially tried instantiating an array, freeCategories, that includes all the word categories, then iterates through the currentPhrase state variable (also an array) and removes each category that is currently in use.

I thought I could just pass freeCategories in the drop target component's props and then use that as the value for 'accept' in useDrop. That just let anything through no matter what was in the freeCategories array.

My second solution was to perform this logic on the drag source object. If the word's category was still available it would be taken out of freeCategories and its type would be "word-usable" or "word-blocked" if it wasn't. With the drop target's accept parameter set to "word-usable" it would still take anything even if its type was returning as "word-blocked".

Finally, I tried adding a canDrop property to useDrop. This checked the freeCategories array (passed in props) against the item's type (now back to the word's category). This caused the drop target to block everything with canDrop returning false even if the word type was in the array of free categories. When I tried switching the monitor from !!monitor.canDrop to !monitor.canDrop, it now looks like it will accept any word, but when dropped it doesn't run the drop function.

The function that builds the jsx of the phrase:

```js
function currentPhraseDisp() {
let freeCategories = ["Form", "Element", "Verb"];
        currentPhrase.forEach(word => freeCategories.splice(freeCategories.indexOf(word.category), 1));
        let startSpace = currentSpell.length < 3 ? <WordSpace start={true} accepts={freeCategories} addWordToCurrentPhrase={addWordToCurrentPhrase} /> : <></>;

return (
<>
            {startSpace}
            {currentPhrase.map((w, i) => {
                return (
                    <div key={i} className="current-phrase-word">
                        <div>{w['word']}</div>
                        <button>-</button>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
</>
)
}
```

Words come through as objects in the format {word: 'word', category: 'word category'}

The dragging logic:

```js
const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
        /*Used in the second solution*/ item: { type: 'word-usable', id: props.word },
        item: { type: props.word.category, id: props.word},
        collect: monitor => ({
            isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
        })
    })
```

The dropping logic:

```js
const [{ isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop({
        accept: props.accepts,

/*Used in solution 3
        canDrop: (item) => {
            props.accepts.includes(item.type);
        },
*/
        drop: (item) => {
            props.addWordToCurrentPhrase(item.id, props.start);
        },
        collect: monitor => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
            canDrop: !!monitor.canDrop()
        })
    })
```

I would like these components to allow the user to drag only one of any given word type into currentPhrase. So far my results have been that the drop target either accepts all words or no words. If anyone can help me understand what react-dnd is doing here, I'd appreciate it because it seems like it won't allow any changes to accept or item types on rerender.